# How do I convert a SQL Server query to Oracle SQLPLus. I am new to Oracle and having problem understanding replacement of if exists and go statement

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, database-migration, ddl

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT abc FROM OBJECTS WHERE NAME = 'BIG' AND type = 'U')
    DROP TABLE FIRSTDATA    
go

CREATE TABLE FIRSTDATA  
(
    ROLLNO varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    STNAME varchar(3) NULL,
)
go

INSERT INTO FIRSTDATA (ROLLNO, STNAME) 
VALUES ('13', 'Becky)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `USER_TABLES` to check if table already exists or not as follows:

```
Declare 
CNT NUMBER:= 0;
BEGIN
SELECT COUNT(1) 
INTO CNT
FROM USER_TABLES
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'FIRSTDATA';

IF CNT = 0 THEN
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE FIRSTDATA 
                      ( ROLLNO varchar(50) NOT NULL, STNAME varchar(3) NULL )' ;
END IF;
END;
/
```

Comment: You'd need to use dynamic SQL for the DDL statement.

Comment: @JustinCave Yeap, That was a mistake. taken care of in an updated answer!! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Note the following about your example:

1. Assuming based on the name that "ROLLNO" is intended to be a number, why are you using a varchar2 data type?
2. You define STNAME as varchar2(3), then insert a value with 5 characters. This will not work.
3. Oracle does not have a native "if exists" clause for DDL commands,
   nor can you execute DDL commands directly within a PL/SQL block -
   you must use an "EXECUTE IMMEDIATE" statement.

A better example would then be:

```
declare
  cnt number;
begin
  select count(*) into cnt from user_tables where table_name = 'FIRSTDATA';

  if cnt > 0 then
    execute immediate 'drop table firstdata';
  end if;
  execute immediate 'create table firstdata (rollno number not null, stname varchar2(30) )';

  execute immediate 'insert into firstdata (rollno, stname) values (:rollno,:stname)' USING 50, 'Becky';
  commit;
end;
/
```

Comment: If you create the table dynamically, subsequent references in the same block would need to use dynamic SQL as well.  Otherwise, if `firstdata` didn't exist, the block would fail to compile and `firstdata` would not be created.

Comment: @JustinCave Good catch! I have updated by response.